# XSLT for-each-group - spurious node in selection

Tags: xslt, foreach

I am inexperienced in XSLT, and need to help to nail a strange bug in a for-each-group loop I am using for an XML transformation solution.
Here is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="trans-unit/target[mrk[following-sibling::text()]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="mrk">
        <mrk>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="name() = 'mrk' and position() = 1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="name() != 'mrk'">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
                </xsl:copy> 
              </xsl:when>         
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </mrk>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The basic idea is to move siblings after an empty `mrk` node within a parent `target` node back inside the `mrk` node.
With the following simplified sample input:

```
<body>
  <trans-unit id="3" phase-name="pretrans" restype="x-p">
      <source>You can add descriptive text notes to a call recording, if you have the appropriate privileges to do so. These notes are visible to all users who have access to the call recording. It is recommended that each user add their initials to the notes to avoid potential confusion.</source>
      <seg-source>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">You can add descriptive text notes to a call recording, if you have the appropriate privileges to do so.</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">These notes are visible to all users who have access to the call recording.</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">It is recommended that each user add their initials to the notes to avoid potential confusion.</mrk>
      </seg-source>
      <target state="final">
        <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1" /><ph ctype="" id="1">&lt;MadCap:variable name="zoom_userdocs_variables.var_product_name" xmlns:MadCap="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd" /&gt;</ph> позволяет находить телефонные взаимодействия, содержащие или не содержащие определенные фразы.
        <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2" />Каждая речевая метка содержит одну или несколько таких фраз.
        <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3" />Ядро <ph ctype="" id="3">&lt;MadCap:variable name="zoom_userdocs_variables.var_product_name" xmlns:MadCap="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd" /&gt;</ph> индексирует медиафайлы и помечает места вхождения фразы (добавляет к ним метки).
        <mrk mtype="seg" mid="4" />Затем нужные медиафайлы можно искать по связанным с ними меткам.
      </target>
  </trans-unit>
</body>
```

I get this output:

```
<body>
  <trans-unit id="3" phase-name="pretrans" restype="x-p">
      <source>You can add descriptive text notes to a call recording, if you have the appropriate privileges to do so. These notes are visible to all users who have access to the call recording. It is recommended that each user add their initials to the notes to avoid potential confusion.</source>
      <seg-source>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">You can add descriptive text notes to a call recording, if you have the appropriate privileges to do so.</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">These notes are visible to all users who have access to the call recording.</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">It is recommended that each user add their initials to the notes to avoid potential confusion.</mrk>
      </seg-source>
      <target state="final">
       <mrk>
        </mrk>
       <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">
          <ph ctype="" id="1">&lt;MadCap:variable name="zoom_userdocs_variables.var_product_name" xmlns:MadCap="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd" /&gt;</ph> позволяет находить телефонные взаимодействия, содержащие или не содержащие определенные фразы.
        </mrk>
       <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">Каждая речевая метка содержит одну или несколько таких фраз.
        </mrk>
       <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">Ядро <ph ctype="" id="3">&lt;MadCap:variable name="zoom_userdocs_variables.var_product_name" xmlns:MadCap="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd" /&gt;</ph> индексирует медиафайлы и помечает места вхождения фразы (добавляет к ним метки).
        </mrk>
       <mrk mtype="seg" mid="4">Затем нужные медиафайлы можно искать по связанным с ними меткам.
      </mrk>
    </target>
  </trans-unit>
</body>
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
<body>
  <trans-unit id="3" phase-name="pretrans" restype="x-p">
      <source>You can add descriptive text notes to a call recording, if you have the appropriate privileges to do so. These notes are visible to all users who have access to the call recording. It is recommended that each user add their initials to the notes to avoid potential confusion.</source>
      <seg-source>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">You can add descriptive text notes to a call recording, if you have the appropriate privileges to do so.</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">These notes are visible to all users who have access to the call recording.</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">It is recommended that each user add their initials to the notes to avoid potential confusion.</mrk>
      </seg-source>
      <target state="final">
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1"><ph ctype="" id="1">&lt;MadCap:variable name="zoom_userdocs_variables.var_product_name" xmlns:MadCap="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd" /&gt;</ph> позволяет находить телефонные взаимодействия, содержащие или не содержащие определенные фразы.</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">Каждая речевая метка содержит одну или несколько таких фраз.</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">Ядро <ph ctype="" id="3">&lt;MadCap:variable name="zoom_userdocs_variables.var_product_name" xmlns:MadCap="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd" /&gt;</ph> индексирует медиафайлы и помечает места вхождения фразы (добавляет к ним метки).</mrk>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="4">Затем нужные медиафайлы можно искать по связанным с ними меткам.</mrk>
      </target>
  </trans-unit>
</body>
```

How can I get rid of the spurious first empty `mrk` child node in the `target` node? I've tried changing the for-each-group select to "*", but then I lose the text nodes. If there's a better way of accomplishing this altogether, I'm all ears! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because your grouping on **node()** is picking up the white space before the very first **mrk** element in your **target** element.

In this case, you could tell the XSLT processor to strip out such space. Try adding the following line to the top of your XSLT (just after the **xsl:output** will do:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="target" />
```

Or if you want to do it for all elements, do this

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Doing this produces the following output

```
<body>
   <trans-unit id="3" phase-name="pretrans" restype="x-p">
      <source>You can add descriptive text notes to a call recording, if you have the appropriate privileges to do so. These notes are visible to all users who have access to the call recording. It is recommended that each user add their initials to the notes to avoid potential confusion.</source>
      <seg-source>
         <mrk mid="1" mtype="seg">You can add descriptive text notes to a call recording, if you have the appropriate privileges to do so.</mrk>
         <mrk mid="2" mtype="seg">These notes are visible to all users who have access to the call recording.</mrk>
         <mrk mid="3" mtype="seg">It is recommended that each user add their initials to the notes to avoid potential confusion.</mrk>
      </seg-source>
      <target state="final">
         <mrk mid="1" mtype="seg">
            <ph ctype="" id="1">&lt;MadCap:variable name="zoom_userdocs_variables.var_product_name" xmlns:MadCap="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd" /&gt;</ph> ������������������ ���������������� �������������������� ����������������������������, �������������������� ������ ���� �������������������� ������������������������ ����������.
        </mrk>
         <mrk mid="2" mtype="seg">������������ �������������� ���������� ���������������� �������� ������ ������������������ ���������� ��������.
        </mrk>
         <mrk mid="3" mtype="seg">�������� <ph ctype="" id="3">&lt;MadCap:variable name="zoom_userdocs_variables.var_product_name" xmlns:MadCap="http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd" /&gt;</ph> ���������������������� �������������������� �� ���������������� ���������� ������������������ ���������� (������������������ �� ������ ����������).
        </mrk>
         <mrk mid="4" mtype="seg">���������� ������������ �������������������� ���������� ������������ ���� ������������������ �� �������� ������������.
      </mrk>
      </target>
   </trans-unit>
</body>
```

(Apologies, my XSLT processor is currently losing the fancy text characters!)

As an aside, although it is not causing the issue, you could actually simplify the following statement

```
 <xsl:when test="name() = 'mrk' and position() = 1">
```

Because you are grouping starting with **mrk** elements, you will only get **mrk** elements in position 1, so you can just do this

```
 <xsl:when test="name() = 'mrk'>
```

(This also means the other **xsl:when** can become an **xsl:otherwise**)

Comment: Excellent - thank you so much for the high speed answer! It works fine. You're right - the 'position' was added by this paranoid beginner, but I guess I should just trust the technology. Removed now.
Going back to the for-each-group loop, why does spurious space get picked up as the first loop iteration? Does XSLT count space as an element in the node() list?

Comment: Text is indeed counted as a node(), so if you haven't told XSLT to strip out white-space, then it will get picked up.